# Xamarin Forms Grid Row Height Much Bigger Than Content

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, grid, row

I am dynamically generating a grid and am filling it with content through C# code. The code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WPapp.Views.Home"
             x:Name="HomeHeader">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
        <ToolbarItem Text="Refresh"
                     x:Name="refreshButton"
                     Clicked="refreshButton_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Margin="10"
                         HorizontalOptions="Center"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         x:Name="HomeContainer"
                         CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true">
                <Label Text="Featured Posts"
                       FontSize="Title"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       Margin="0, 20, 10, 0"/>
                <StackLayout x:Name="FeaturedContainer"
                             CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true">
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
int columnNum = 0;
int rowNum = 0;
foreach (var category in categoryList)
{
    Grid postGrid = new Grid();
    var column = new ColumnDefinition();
    column.Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);
    postGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
    postGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
    double division = featuredPosts.Count / 2;
    double rowCount = Math.Ceiling(division);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        var row = new RowDefinition();
        row.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        postGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    }

    foreach (var item in featuredPosts)
    {
        Frame featuredFrame = new Frame();
        featuredFrame.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
        featuredFrame.CornerRadius = 5;
        featuredFrame.Padding = 20;

        Label postTitle = new Label();
        postTitle.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Subtitle, typeof(Label));
        postTitle.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;

        BoxView titleSeparator = new BoxView();
        titleSeparator.Color = Color.Gray;
        titleSeparator.HeightRequest = 1;
        titleSeparator.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;

        Image postFeaturedImage = new Image();
        postFeaturedImage.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;

        BoxView imageSeparator = new BoxView();
        imageSeparator.Color = Color.Gray;
        imageSeparator.HeightRequest = 2;
        imageSeparator.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;

        Label publishDate = new Label();
        publishDate.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label));

        StackLayout postDetails = new StackLayout();
        postDetails.Children.Add(postTitle);
        postDetails.Children.Add(titleSeparator);
        postDetails.Children.Add(postFeaturedImage);
        postDetails.Children.Add(imageSeparator);
        postDetails.Children.Add(publishDate);

        featuredFrame.Content = postDetails;

        if ((featuredPosts.First() == item) && !(featuredPosts.Count() % 2 == 0))
        {
            postGrid.Children.Add(featuredFrame, columnNum, rowNum);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(featuredFrame, 2);
            columnNum++;
        }
        else
        {
            postGrid.Children.Add(featuredFrame, columnNum, rowNum);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(featuredFrame, 1);
        }          
        columnNum++;
        if (columnNum == 2)
        {
            rowNum++;
            columnNum = 0;
        }
    }
    FeaturedContainer.Children.Add(postGrid);
    columnNum = 0;
    rowNum = 0;
}
```

With this code, this is the result I am getting:

[image: Result Screenshot]

As you can see, the top-left grid height is sized correctly as it is just big enough to fit its children. This is how it should be.

However, the problem is, sometimes the grid cell becomes too big, this is shown in the bottom-left and bottom-right cells. It is too tall! This is only for some of the cells.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this so the grid height is just big enough, not too big.

Comment: Have you tried changing `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to `VerticalOptions="Fill"` ?

Comment: Changing the HomeContainer VerticalOptions to Fill in the XAML file does nothing

Comment: You can set a specific height for you Image to make a test. Or you can set the all images to the same url, if you will get the same issue.

Comment: Try using CollectionView instead of constructing that grid manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/